# I want to trace the recursive code that I have written

Tags: python-3.x, recursion, path, tree, tree-traversal

I am novice to recursion, I have written **code to find the path of a given node**, when I dry run my code(**trace the stack**) it is giving the right answer but when I am running the same on machine it is not showing the expected output can someone please help me in **tracing out the code**(e.g. using the call stack)?

```
    class NewNode:
        def __init__(self, data):
            self.data = data
            self.left = self.right = None
    
    
    arr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]
    q = []
    
    
    def create_level_order_binary_tree(i):
        root = None
        if i < len(arr):
            root = NewNode(arr[i])
            root.left = create_level_order_binary_tree(2 * i + 1)
            root.right = create_level_order_binary_tree(2 * i + 2)
        return root
    
    def dfs(root, p, temp_path, path):
        print(temp_path)
        if root is None:
            return path
        if root.data == p:
            if len(temp_path) == 0:
                path.append(root.data)
                return path
            else:
                temp_path.append(root.data)
                path.append(temp_path)
                return path
        temp_path.append(root.data)
        path = dfs(root.left, 6, temp_path, path)
        if len(path) == 0:
            path = dfs(root.right, 6, temp_path, path)
        return path
    
     
 root_node = create_level_order_binary_tree(0)
 path_to_node = dfs(root_node, 6, [], [])
 print(path_to_node`enter code here`)
```

Comment: Are you using an IDE that includes a graphical debugger?  If you are, you can set breakpoints at strategic points and track the program flow and depending on the debugger list the stack as well.

Comment: Why are you forcing dfs to search for node 6 in the two statements toward the bottom of the function?  specifically ```path = dfs(root.left, 6, temp_path, path)``` should probably be modified to be making a recursive call to either right or left node from current node.

Comment: I am trying to search for '6' in left subtree and if it's not present (i.e. path's length = 0) then I am searching it in right subtree, @itprorh66 can you please tell me the output as when I dry run the same program I got some output and on machine, it's giving some different output, so I am not getting what is the bug, like why I am not able to get the bug by tracing the stack!

Comment: Have you walked through your code using a debugger?

Comment: Your problem lies in the fact that once you trace down the left side of the tree from the root and don't find the requested p value, you never go back and trace down the right side of the path from the root.  For this recursion to work once you reach a node with a None value on the left, you must check the right path.  If you can't find it there, you must go back one node and check the right path of the prior node.  If you properly implement the recursion, you will ultimately return to the root node and will then start down the right node from root.,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following are two approaches to solving your problem.  While I haven't timed the routines, I suspect the non-recursive approach will be faster, since it doesn't utilize the stack as much.

First using a non-recursive approach employing a simple stack (Last In First Out) data structure.

```
from copy import deepcopy
def nrc_dfs(nde, p):
    stck = [(nde, [])]  #LIFO stack implementation
    while stck:
        nd, pth = stck.pop(len(stck)-1)   #pop lastv entry
        if nd:
            pth.append(nd.data)
            if nd.data == p:
                return pth
            stck.append((nd.right, deepcopy(pth)))
            stck.append((nd.left, deepcopy(pth)))
    return []
```

The second approach, using a recursive technique.

```
def rc_dfs(nde, p):
    def dfs_sch(nde, p, path):
        if nde:
            path.append(nde.data)
            if nde.data == p:
                return path
            pl = dfs_sch(nde.left, p, [])
            if pl:
                path.extend(pl)
                return path
            pr = dfs_sch(nde.right, p, [])
            if pr:
                path.extend(pr)
                return path
        return []
    return dfs_sch(nde, p, [])
```